# Python Script to configure (via SSH) Cisco Switches

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pexpect

I have a lot of cisco switches and routers in my environment. I have three sets of credentials (only one of them works with a particular device. I then have the IPs listed in a notepad (sub.txt). And the configuration in another notepad (config.txt)

The aim is to push the configurations (line by line) from config.txt to the list of list of IP via SSH. If the command is accepted by the devices, a log should be put into success.txt and if the command is not accepted for some reason, a log should be appended to fail.txt

But this does not work. Can you please help me fix?

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import logging
import socket
import pexpect
import traceback
from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn



remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ips = [i.strip() for i in open("sub.txt")] 
user_local = "user1"
pass_local = "pass1"
user_aspac = "user2"
pass_aspac = "pass2"
user_batcca = "user3"
pass_batcca = "pass3"

g = open('config.txt', 'r+')
str = g.read()
g.close

success = open('success.txt', 'a')
fail = open('failed.txt', 'a')

paramiko.util.log_to_file("paramiko.log")

for ip in ips:
    try:
        remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=user_local, password=pass_local, timeout=4, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
        #print ("SSH connection established to %s" + ip)
        remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
        print (ip + ' === local credential')
        #remote_conn.send("show switch\n")
        remote_conn.send((str))
        time.sleep(2) 
        output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
        print (output)

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        try:
            remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=user_aspac, password=pass_aspac, timeout=4, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
            remote_conn1 = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print ip + ' === Global Credentials'
            #output = remote_conn.recv(500)
            #remote_conn.send("show switch")
            #remote_conn.send("\n")
            remote_conn1.send((str))
            time.sleep(2) 
            output1 = remote_conn1.recv(5000)
            print (output1)
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            try:
                #remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=user_batcca, password=pass_batcca, timeout=4, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
                #remote_conn2 = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
                child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('ssh ' + user_batcca + '@' + ip)
                child.expect ('[pP]assword:')
                child.sendline(pass_batcca)
                print ip + ' === BATCCA Credential'
                #output2 = remote_conn2.recv(5000)
                for line in open('Config.txt').xreadlines():
                    child.sendline(line)
                    i = child.expect (['#', '^'])
                    if i==0:
                        success.write(ip + '\t' + line +'\n')
                    elif i==1:
                        fail.write(ip + '\t' + line +'\n')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    output2 = child.recv(5000)
                    print (output2)

            except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
                print ip + ' === Bad credentials'
                remote_conn3 = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
                output3 = remote_conn3.recv(5000)
                print (output3)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print ip + ' === Issues with ssh service'
    except socket.error:
        print ip + ' === Device unreachable'
```